# Passing arguments to bash command after eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing, conda

While creating a conda environment and running some python code in it, from a bash script, I was experiencing some difficulties in passing a variable to the command.

### Example 1

This is the hardcoded command which does work.

```
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
cd some-repository && conda deactivate && conda activate some-environment && python -m code.project1.src --some-arg
```

### MWE

Here is an example that does not process the variable in the command:

```
# bash -c "some_test"
some_test() {
    echo "PWD=$PWD"
    eval "$(conda shell.bash hook && export env_var=some-dir)"
    cd $env_var
    echo "PWD=$PWD"
}
```

Which outputs:

```
PWD=/home/name/git/some-repo
PWD=/home/name
```

### Question

How can I pass variables to the commands that are being executed after `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"`?

Comment: The `conda activate` command is meant for interactive shell sessions - not situations like this. Use `conda run` instead. Basically the whole thing could be done with: `conda run -n some-environment python -m code.project1.src --some-arg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval "$(command)"` executes the output of the command line. So you need to output the variable assignment, not execute it in the command.

You're executing the variable assignment in the subshell of `$()`, so none of its variable assignments persist into the calling shell.

```
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook && echo export env_var=some-dir)"
```

But I'm not sure why you need to do that inside the `$()`. You can just write

```
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
export env_var=some-dir
```